# CSS center three inline block buttons

Tags: html, css, button

I have three buttons,

```html
<button class="align" id="decrease">decrease</button>
<button class="align" id="reset">reset</button>
<button class="align" id="increase">increase</button>
```

and a CSS class,

```css
.align{
    position: absolute;
    right: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

that centers some buttons, but the end result looks like this:

[image: What the buttons look like on page]

Is there a way I could center them while keeping them separated, or do I have to assign them each a separate class?

I expected them to be separated because of the `display: inline-block;`, but they just stack on top of each other. I've tried giving them margin, but that has not worked.

Comment: The problem is `position: absolute` (as it so often is), why are you using that approach instead of an easier `display: grid` or `display: flex`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of options. The simplest is to put `text-align:center;` on the container element, in this case `<body>`. Or I also show how you can get even more control. For example, here I have active a grid with a small gap between each "column" and `5em` width, so they all take up the same space. Note `16px` = `1em` in most modern browsers by default, but I set it as a base anyway. So `5em` would be 5 x 16 pixels = 80 pixels.

***Note***: on *both* these you can remove the `.align{ display: inline-block; }` but that was your question thus I left that in.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.align{ display: inline-block; }
/* note this is the "container" but it could be a div or some other element */

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 5em);
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<button class="align" id="decrease">decrease</button> <button class="align" id="reset">reset</button> <button class="align" id="increase">increase</button>
```

The simplest option:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.align{ display: inline-block; }
/* note this is the "container" but it could be a div or some other element */

body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<button class="align" id="decrease">decrease</button> <button class="align" id="reset">reset</button> <button class="align" id="increase">increase</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can align the three buttons with just a [Flexbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout) parent container:

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;}

.control-button {margin: 0 5px;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="control-button" id="decrease">decrease</button>
  <button class="control-button" id="reset">reset</button>
  <button class="control-button" id="increase">increase</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

To center the buttons while keeping them separated, you can make a slight adjustment to your CSS. You can apply `text-align: center;` to the parent container, and then you can set `display: inline-block;` on the buttons.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You've probably noticed the "warm welcome" of 3 downvotes already on your answer, and while I didn't downvote, perhaps I can help you understand (possibly) why they occurred.  First, telling someone they could have Googled something or looked it up on ChatGPT is typically considered "unfriendly" language.  Further, if it's a common question, then it will often be closed with a duplicate, and it shouldn't be answered in the first place.  Finally - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1